# Why does the access time for the first element of a data.frame depends on its dimensions?

Tags: r, time-complexity

I have difficulties with the access time to the first element of a `data.frame`. The access times seem to depend on the size of the `data.frame`. Does anyone know how to eliminate this dependency?

This is a code example I have run. It allocates "tme" that saves the times required to set the first element of a `data.frame` of `length` `i*1000`, where `i` runs from 1 to 500. Essentially, I allocate longer and longer `data.frames` in steps of 1000 and set the first element to zero. In short `data.frames` the access times are far below measurability, they rise to several seconds in long arrays.

```
tme <- (1:500)
for (j in 1:500){
  i <- j*1000
  vec <- (1:(i*1000))
  print(i)
  now <- Sys.time()
  vec[1] <- 0
  tme[j] <- Sys.time()-now
}
tme_vec_first <- tme
```

Comment: Huh? I don't see a data.frame anywhere near this code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think the increase in time is related to access time, but is rather due to making copies. Each of these assignments involves making a copy of the vector. You can test this with `tracemem`.

```
# initialize vector (10 zeros)
tracemem({vec <- integer(10)})
```

> [1] "<0000000011D48720>"

```
# assign value to 7th position
tracemem({vec[7] <- 6L})
```

> tracemem[0x0000000011d48720 -> 0x00000000111a02b0]:
>   [1] "<0000000012E25468>"

As the vector grows larger, the time involved in the copy process increases.

---

Further, note that `vec <- (1:(i*1000))` is an integer vector, and `vec[1] <- 0` turns vec into a double vector, which roughly doubles the size of the vector in memory.

First, we'll create the integer vector, and check it's size and type.

```
# start over with similar syntax to question
tracemem({vec <- 1:10})
```

> [1] "<0000000011E55508>"

# check size
    object.size(vec)

> 88 bytes

```
# check type
typeof(vec)
```

> [1] "integer"

Now, assign assign 0 to the 7th position and re-check size and type. 0 appears to be the same value as the value that is there initially, but is actually a double rather than an integer.

```
# assign value
tracemem({vec[7] <- 0})
```

> tracemem[0x0000000011e55508 -> 0x0000000012399390]:
>   tracemem[0x0000000012399390 -> 0x0000000013394740]:
>   [1] "<00000000130EBA60>"

```
# check size
object.size(vec)
```

> 168 bytes

```
# check type
typeof(vec)
```

> [1] "double"

Notice here, that there are two separate copy instructions. My guess is that the first is the copy to convert the vector from integer into double and the second is the assignment.

To keep the vector as an integer vector, use `vec[1] <- 0L` instead as "L" tells R that an integer is desired.

---

Note that this copying behavior `tracemem` is observed both with Rstudio and Rgui in using MS R open 3.2.5 with windows 7.

Comment: I thought R was optimising these copies away. Apparently not.

Comment: In which version of R are these copies being made? Generally (and unless `vec` is referenced by another object), `vec` should not be copied when assigned an "integer" and be copied (coerced) only once when assigned a "double". Oh, unless it's in Rstudio? I think I remember something similar again on SO

Comment: I'm using 3.2.3 MS Revo Open at the moment. I was fairly surprised about the copies as no copies was my understanding as well. I'll try to remember to verify this with 3.3.1 patched in a couple of hours, but I now suspect I'll get the same result.

Comment: Nice explanation of the core concepts @Imo