# R copies for no apparent reason

Tags: r

Some R function will make R copy the object AFTER the function call, like nrow, while some others don't, like sum.
For example the following code:

```
x = as.double(1:1e8)
system.time(x[1] <- 100)
y = sum(x)
system.time(x[1] <- 200)     ## Fast (takes 0s), after calling sum
foo = function(x) {
    return(sum(x))
}
y = foo(x)
system.time(x[1] <- 300)     ## Slow (takes 0.35s), after calling foo
```

Calling foo is NOT slow, because x isn't copied. However, changing x again is very slow, as x is copied. My guess is that calling foo will leave a reference to x, so when changing it after, R makes another copy.

Any one knows why R does this? Even when the function doesn't change x at all? Thanks.

Comment: I am using RevolutionR Open 3.1.2. Here is my results:

   user  system elapsed 
      0       0       0
   user  system elapsed 
      0       0       0 
   user  system elapsed 
   0.20    0.13    0.33

Comment: Revolution R doesn't exist any more... might want to upgrade. Fwiw, I see the same thing you do on vanilla R 3.2.5.

Comment: Any idea why R does this? It seems no reason to make a copy when changing it AFTER the function call. Thanks.

Comment: This may be related: https://developer.r-project.org/Refcnt.html I don't know C or the R internals well enough to know how to determine the # references to an object at a given time.

Comment: `y = foo(x)` incremented the named attribute of `x` from 1 to 2, which forces the subsequent copy. Probably because R can't know for sure what side effects `foo` may have had. _You_ know that `foo` won't do anything strange, but it may be nearly impossible for R to know that in general.

Comment: I can generate positive system time with `x = as.double(1:1e8); system.time(x[1] <- 100); system.time(x[1] <- 100); system.time(x[1] <- 100);`. with MS R open 3.2.5. Also, wrapping `x[1] <- 100` in `tracemem` indicates copies are being made.

Comment: @Frank `.Internal(inspect(x))` will tell you what the NAMED property is for an object, but I always have to remember to not do that stuff in RStudio, because for some reason the way it handles R everything comes back with NAMED of 2.

Comment: Regarding @joran's comment, "_not do that stuff in RStudio_": [Operator “[<-” in RStudio and R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559387/operator-in-rstudio-and-r).

Comment: Here is a [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38766068/why-does-the-access-time-for-the-first-element-of-a-data-frame-depends-on-its-di/38766520#38766520).

Comment: @Frank Thanks for pointing out the link. It is very useful. Does anyone know when SWITCH_TO_REFCNT will be the default for compiling R? Or is there a compiled version of R for windows 10 with SWITCH_TO_REFCNT enabled? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I definitely recommend Hadley's [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/) book, as it digs into some of the internals that you will likely find interesting and relevant.  Most relevant to your question (and as mentioned by @joran and @lmo), the reason for the slow-down was an additional reference that forced *copy-on-modify*.

An excerpt that might be beneficial from [Memory#Modification](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html#modification):

> There are two possibilities:
>
> - R modifies x in place.
> - R makes a copy of x to a new location, modifies the copy, and then
>     uses the name x to point to the new location.
>
> It turns out that R can do either depending on the circumstances. In
>   the example above, it will modify in place. But if another variable
>   also points to x, then R will copy it to a new location. To explore
>   what’s going on in greater detail, we use two tools from the pryr
>   package. Given the name of a variable, address() will tell us the
>   variable’s location in memory and refs() will tell us how many names
>   point to that location.

Also of interest are the sections on [R's C interface](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/C-interface.html) and [Performance](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Performance.html).  The [`pryr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pryr/index.html) package also has tools for working with these sorts of internals in an easier fashion.

One last note from Hadley's book (same Memory section) that might be helpful:

> While determining that copies are being made is not hard, preventing
>   such behaviour is. If you find yourself resorting to exotic tricks to
>   avoid copies, it may be time to rewrite your function in C++, as
>   described in [Rcpp](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html#rcpp).